# Maven - Force to use dependency

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies

I made custom dependency which uses spring 4.x version and I include it in a project which uses spring 3.x version. When a method from this dependency is called it uses classes from spring 3.x version not from 4.x. Is it possible to force this dependency to use spring 4.x whereas the project itself will use spring 3.x ?

Comment: you need to find what is the dependency that you are overriding and exclude that  and include corresponding 4.x dependency

Comment: you will also run into runtime issues if you mix and max versions of spring. You wont be able to do this. Upgrade the project using spring 3 or make them seperate runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible due to the fact that, when finally project is running, the dependencies are resolved on the basis of group id and artifact id and not on their version. Which is why your application is using 3.x dependency as it is overriding the one mentioned in the parent project. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can if you separate your application (which you probably don't want to). Another approach: You might think about using another class loader within the same JVM. This, however, leads to a probably bigger bunch of problems, especially using Spring.

[Dzone article](https://dzone.com/articles/java-classloader-handling) about loading the same class from libs with different versions.

Answer (score 0):

As pvpkiran noted, you want to exclude the spring v3 transitive dependency from your custom artifact. From the maven documentation - [Optional Dependencies and Dependency Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
            <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
            <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```